# How to avoid CSV injection on fields containing URLs?

Tags: node.js, regex, csv, code-injection, csv-injection

I am trying to secure my application preventing CSV injection. The vulnerability applies when the user downloads a CSV export file.

The way I deal with it now is removing the characters: **= + - @**

> https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/CSV_Injection

The problem is that I have on the database a '*Description*' field that includes URLs inside.
If I check if the characters exist and escape the characters it will break also the URLs.

Is there a way to deal with this problem maybe via Regex?

Example:

```
Description = "This is a big description......https://url.com......=10+20+cmd|' /C calc'!A0....";
```

Expected behavior:

the url should **not** be escaped.

the excel command should be escaped.

Technologies used: NodeJS, Sequelize, MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the page you cite states (emphasis mine):

> To remediate it, ensure that no cells **begin with** any of the following characters:

In other words, you don't have to remove *all* of those characters, only when they stand at the start of a value. And that should not happen very often with real-world data.